# How to ask Blender to return an angle of a tangent in a driver?

Tags: python

My vehicle is driving along it’s locale Y-axis. When it encounters a hill the empty on the front lifts up and creates an angle with the empty at the rear.  How can I ask Blender to return the angle in a driver math expression for the vehicle to rotate on its X-axis. See image.

The Y is known as a fixed construction value of the verhicle (6 meter)

Z = ( z-location Empty Front) – (z-location Empty Rear)

To calculate the tangent in the driver :

Var_1 = z-location Empty Front

Var_2 = z-location Empty Rear

Expression for tangent : (Var_1 – Var_2) / 6

So I have the tangent, how do I get the angle ?

I tryed this : arctan((var_1-var_2)/6), but Blender sais ERROR : invalid Python expression

[image]

Comment: Consider a track to constraint. eg track the axis empty to the other, giving it the rotation required.

Comment: For a ‘Track to’ constraint I have to use bones, it doesn’t work that well with empties I did the test. It is a decision I have to make ; bones or empties. I just started rigging my vehicle, still have to do the tracks. Don’t know yet were I will end. It doesn’t matter fooling around, testing out ideas and learning in the process. Thank you for pointing that out to me.

Answer (score 1):

The python function is atan() not arctan(), and generally its better to use atan2(y, x) instead of atan(y/x) because the former won't generate division by zero.

Also note you have the hypotense so you want asin(var_1-var_2)/6) to get $\alpha$ since you haven't actually found Y. See https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/drivers_panel.html#simple-expressions

Comment: atan((var_1-var_2)/6) and asin((var_1-var_2)/6) work perfectly.

I must do something wrong with atan2((var_1-var_2)/6) Blender gives the error ‘Invalid Python expression’

Thank you very much for helping me out :-))

Comment: atan2((var_1-var_2), 6) with two arguments, but again, this is incorrect because 6 is the hypotenuse not what you have labeled 'Y'.

Comment: atan((var_1-var_2)/6) and asin((var_1-var_2)/6) works perfectly.
Here is a little video, my first start to animate  my tracked lander on shore (WIP): www.dolores74.com/blender/tangent.mp4 
Thank you very much for helping me out :-))

Comment: Say thank you by upvoting and accepting the answer. Nice job of the video!